# Which scripture says, "Where Women are Worshiped, Devtas reside there"?

Tags: women, reference-request

In which scripture it is written that "यत्र नार्यस्तु पूज्यन्ते, रमन्ते तत्र देवताः" (yatra naryastu pujyante tatra devta ramante), which means - "Where women are worshiped , Devatas reside there" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Manu Smriti 3.56](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199834.html):

> यत्र नार्यस्तु पूज्यन्ते रमन्ते तत्र देवताः ।
> यत्रैतास्तु न पूज्यन्ते सर्वास्तत्राफलाः क्रियाः ॥ ५६ ॥
>
> yatra nāryastu pūjyante ramante tatra devatāḥ |
> yatraitāstu na pūjyante sarvāstatrāphalāḥ kriyāḥ || 56 ||
>
> Where women are honoured, there the gods rejoice; where, on the other hand, they are not honoured, there all rites are fruitless.